# Convert SCSI Tape Auto-Loader to iSCSI Target

Tags: backup, virtualization, iscsi

We're currently in the process of re-evaluating our server backup process. Currently we're using Backup Exec 11d to backup all our server as though they are all physical servers, performing Full/incremental jobs directly to our Adic Faststor 2 Autoloader.

What we're looking at is upgrading to Backup Exec 12.5, and moving to a backup-to-disk-to-tape solution where we have an online copy of the data on disk, and offload to tape at the end of the month for off-site storage.

As part of this, we want to virtualize our backup server. Using an iSCSI target as the location for our online backup is easy enough, but I'm having trouble getting info about iSCSI solutions for the tape offload. As a way to try and keep costs down, I was curious if we'd be able to use a SCSI-to-iSCSI bridge to convert our existing tape autoloader until a later date when we can get additional budget. i.e. Would something like this (http://www.quantum.com/Products/Connectivity/Index.aspx) work for us?

Has anyone else tried to use a bridge in this type of scenario?

Answer (score 3):

Tackled Archon, it can be easily done with Tape Redirector, which allows you to share the existing physical tape as an iSCSI device. BTW, it's for free. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/download-starwind-tape-redirector

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used a bridge, but I have done this using the ietd software iscsi target stack, and a patch to allow raw IO.  This may be a viable option for you

Notes on this are available at [www.wlug.org.nz/iSCSINotes](http://www.wlug.org.nz/iSCSINotes). Key points are to export both the loader and the tape device as separate LUNs under the same target.

There's more on the actual patch process, including some additional notes about a newer patch required for newer kernel / ietd versions at [www.wlug.org.nz/XenNotes](http://www.wlug.org.nz/XenNotes).

Comment: is the same possible using tgtd instead of ietd?

Comment: dyasny: I haven't tried myself, but I have heard that it does not work. (There's a few howto type pages that suggest it does, but in a vague enough manner that I suspect the authors just assumed it would, as none of them actually go into any detail regarding tape)

Answer (score 1):

I am very sorry for being off topic, but I have the exact same needs.

**"Moving to a backup-to-disk-to-tape solution where we have an online copy of the data on disk and offload to tape at the end of the month for off-site storage."**

The only difference is that we are mostly Windows shop so that ties our hands a bit.

I would be happy to hear, is there are any similar solutions for the Windows OS.